# Timber Android in an Android Library project

Tags: android, timber

I am wondering if is there any way to use Timber Android in an Android library project, without initiate it in `onCreate()` in `Application` Class ?

Answer (score 1):

So it depends when you want to initialize your library. You can plant a DebugTree for example in your Library init class and if your library is initialized in your Application class or the better way would be to abstract it a little bit and make it possible to give your library a logger instance for example so that in debug builds it would be possible to pass some logger. So it is recommended to plant the tree as early as possible but this is not a must but you may be too late for some important logs

> Behavior is added through Tree instances. You can install an instance by calling Timber.plant. Installation of Trees should be done as early as possible. The onCreate of your application is the most logical choice. https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/README.md

So like i already said you need to decide when and how you want to do enable logs for your lib (only debug etc..) and when your library will be instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i will just add that, my Android Library will be used in other applications as a library, so i can not intialize it in the onCreate because I don't have Application Class in my Android Library project.

Comment: Yes but the applications that will use your library still needs to initialize it somewhere except you only have static methods in your lib